# Why does the Fast Day leyning skip verses?

Tags: torah-reading, fast-days

Why does the Torah reading for public fast days skip pesukim? My sense is that this is the only Torah reading in which this procedure is followed. Are there any others?

Comment: Every day of Yom Tov (except Chol HaMoed Sukkot) skips verses. So does Rosh Chodesh Tevet. And all of the 4-Parshiot.

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol23Katz.pdf